# What does the word "go" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

The person talking speaks about an organization called Camarilla.

"Camarilla, on the other hand, suspends judgment entirely...or **so goes the party line**."

I know that "party line" means "policy" from the following definition I found.
The agenda, policy, or ideology of a particular political party. Often used in the plural.(source TFD)

I know that "go" can mean
24. to be phrased, written, or composed: How does that song go?(source TFD)

Does **so goes the party line** mean "The policy is written that way"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what it means. The [Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go) is:

> 15a: to be in phrasing or expression : READ
> // as the story *goes*